# WPF Binding data from two controls

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf-binding

Im trying to bind custom property from one control to another, here code:

First, my custom TreeViewControl

```
public partial class ItemTreeControl : UserControl
{
    readonly ItemTreeViewModel itemTreeViewModel;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem",
                                    typeof(Item), 
                                    typeof(ItemTreeControl),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(Item)));

    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (Item)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Here goes another custom control for displaying details:

```
public partial class ItemDetailControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DetailItemProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("DetailItem",
                                         typeof(Item),
                                         typeof(ItemDetailControl),
                                         new PropertyMetadata(default(Item)));

    public Item DetailItem
    {
        get { return (Item)GetValue(DetailItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DetailItemProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Now XAML code with binding:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemTreeControl x:Name="itemTreeControl"/>
    <ItemDetailControl DetailItem="{Binding ElementName=itemTreeControl,
                                      Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Now, if a new value arrives at  `ItemTreeControl.SelectedItem`, value in `ItemDetailControl.DetailItem` dont change. Why?

UPDATED.

Code-behind in a `ItemTreeControl`:

```
private void myTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if (e.NewValue is ItemViewModel)
    {
         SelectedItem = (e.NewValue as ItemViewModel).Item;
    }
    else
    {
        SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: An interesting part of the code is how the value arrives to the `SelectedItem` which is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

In general UI controls do not bind to each other's properties. `SelectedItem` is a so much ideal to be kept at the ViewModel level. If you have a VM underlying these controls, you should really bind both these controls to a VM-level property.

Also note that the Detail control normally doesn't change the SelectedItem, so that binding should not be `TwoWay`.

Comment: But how can i get property `SelectedItem` from `ItemTreeControl`s ViewModel, and pass it to the `ItemDetailControl`?

Comment: There would most probably be a single ViewModel behind your View, defining a `SelectedItem` member therein. Both the controls will bind to that member. If you're using MVVM Light or some other library, you already have something like `RaisePropertyChanged` that you can call inside your property setter to allow your controls to be notified of the updated property value.